# Update listbox ROWSOURCE when making a selection from a drop down

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have scoured around for topics relating to the idea of changing a listbox recordsource using VBA and I have created my own piece.. but it only works 1/2 way.

I have a form for tracking attendance issues for associates.. We have 2 locations, 1 in Az and 1 in Tx.. Due to recent laws that changed in Az our policies were updated.. The difference is in Az an occurrence is held for 1 year (or 365 days) and in Tx the occurrence is held for 3 months (90 days).

The basic idea is this:
   If the text box for "supervisor state" = Az, the HISTORYBOX should show/calculate out 365 days of records.. else if the "supervisor state" = Tx then the HISTORYBOX should show/calculate 90 days of records.

My issue is when selecting an AZ supervisor.. it is still pulling the 90 day version of the code.. not the 365 day version.

Here is the code I have been able to create so far:

```
Public Sub ChangeHistory()


Dim strSQL As String

If Me.txtsupervisorstate.Value = "AZ" Then

strSQL = "SELECT OccuTable.ValueOfOccurance, " & _
  "              OccuTable.Short_Code_Occurance, " & _
  "              OccuTable.OccuranceDate, " & _
  "              OccuTable.Roll_Off_Date, " & _
  "              OccuTable.Notes, " & _
  "              OccuTable.AssociatedIDNumber " & _
  " FROM OccuTable GROUP BY OccuTable.ValueOfOccurance, " & _
                              " OccuTable.Short_Code_Occurance, " & _
                              " OccuTable.OccuranceDate, " & _
                              " OccuTable.Roll_Off_Date, " & _
                              " OccuTable.Notes, " & _
                              " OccuTable.AssociatedIDNumber " & _
                                 " WHERE (((OccuTable.OccuranceDate) Between 
Date() And Date()-365) And " & _
                                " 
((OccuTable.AssociatedIDNumber)=Forms!OccuranceTracker!txtAssociateID)) 
ORDER BY OccuTable.OccuranceDate DESC;"

ElseIf Me.txtsupervisorstate.Value = "TX" Then

strSQL = " SELECT OccuTable.ValueOfOccurance, " & _
  "              OccuTable.Short_Code_Occurance, " & _
  "              OccuTable.OccuranceDate, " & _
  "              OccuTable.Roll_Off_Date, " & _
  "              OccuTable.Notes, " & _
  "              OccuTable.AssociatedIDNumber " & _
  " FROM OccuTable GROUP BY OccuTable.ValueOfOccurance, " & _
                              " OccuTable.Short_Code_Occurance, " & _
                              " OccuTable.OccuranceDate, " & _
                              " OccuTable.Roll_Off_Date, " & _
                              " OccuTable.Notes, " & _
                              " OccuTable.AssociatedIDNumber " & _
                                 " WHERE (((OccuTable.OccuranceDate) Between 
Date() And Date()-90) And 
((OccuTable.AssociatedIDNumber)=Forms!OccuranceTracker!txtAssociateID)) 
ORDER BY OccuTable.OccuranceDate DESC;"
Me.listBoxPastOccurances.RowSource = strSQL

End If

Call SumOfOccu
End Sub
```

Here is what the form looks like:

[AttendanceForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rstZo.gif)

Comment: Have you step-debugged? Is value of txtsupervisorstate actually AZ? Don't need to type `.Value` because that is default property. You don't show code in the ElseIf. It is not necessary to repeat the entire SQL statement. Since OccurranceDate is not an aggregate calc, perhaps you should use WHERE instead of HAVING.

Comment: Suggest you use If Then Else to set a variable to the correct days value then concatenate that into the SQL string so the string does not have to be repeated in code.

Comment: I have tried to step debug (pressing f8 to step through each line) with nothing useful that stopped it from working or showing me where it went wrong.. I am new(ish) to VBA, specifically debugging.  

I attached a screen shot of the form in my OP showing that the text box exists and has the "AZ" value.. 

I didn't retype/copy and paste the elseif as it would have just elongated the post unnecessarily as there is literally a difference of like 3 characters.

I tried changing HAVING to WHERE with no luck.

Comment: I was going to originally use a regular if value = AZ then code for 365 else code for 90, but the logic requires the code to be written out 2 times anyway does it not?  If I can shorten the code I am all for it.

Comment: No it does not, as @June7 was saying, you would basically have a "main" SQL String, and the `WHERE` portion would just pass a parameter or concatonate the two pieces together, whichever you prefer. Something like strSQL = "SELECT ..." > "HAVING ... " (or WHERE) then remove the date restriction, and just put that portion into the IF statement like strSQL & " Date()-365" / strSQL & " Date()-90".

Comment: What I am not getting here is how you can possibly be seeing the issue you are seeing when the code (in its current state) cannot even come to the conclusion that you have mentioned that it is (as an error). Regardless if the `Me.txtsupervisorstate.Value` is giving the value you expect, there is no way for it to pull the 90 day version as it stands. What you might want to try and do is ignore the SQL for now and just make sure you can get the `IF` statement to go where it is supposed to, like with say... a MsgBox test or a DebugPrint, etc.

Comment: I added in the rest of the code (originally left it out just to keep the overall post length shorter) as it sits in my form currently.  The way I know its not running correctly is when I test it against associates where I have manually calculated their occurrence values.. If you look at the ATTENDANCEFORM link in my OP, it will show a total of 3.5.. that number should be 10.5.. the 3.5 is from the last 90 days.. 10.5 would be for the last 365 days..  It doesn't matter if I load an AZ or TX leader first.. it still defaults to the 90 days.  I will be testing with a msgbox today as you suggessted

Comment: I should also point out I moved the code to its own sub.. then that sub is called from the combo box click event.. from there it will call the sum of occurrences.. I am trying to segregate and locate the issue just in case its not in the SQL string.. will get back to you after some more testing.

Comment: Ok, finally gotten a valid error to show up for me.. Still not sure what the correct fix for it is.. (Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'occutable.associateIDnumber WHERE (((occutable.occurancedata) between Date() and Date()-90 and ((occutable.assocaiteIDnumber)=Forms!occurancetracker!txtassociateID))".

Looking for a syntax error now.. Will update if I find it.

Comment: your assignment to the rowsource is not in the first IF stateament (Me.listBoxPastOccurances.RowSource = strSQL) or you can just place it outside of your entire IF block, since all you're doing is creating strSQL statements.   Assign it to the rowsource after you're done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my goodness I was WAYYY overthinking this issue.  My newish self to VBA was trying to find the most convoluted and confusing way to make this work.. After ALOT of research around StackOverflow I found that I can write a query and save that query for future use.. So I wrote 2 individual queries (Occurrences365 and Occurrences90).. These duplicated the original query for the listbox (when I only needed the 90 day version), which was known to work; which made creating the 365 day version super simple.

Then I was able to reduce all my other convoluted code down to this:

```
Public Sub ClearHistory()

If Me![txtsupervisorstate] = "AZ" Then

Me![listBoxPastOccurances].RowSource = "Occurrences365"

ElseIf Me![txtsupervisorstate] = "TX" Then

Me![listBoxPastOccurances].RowSource = "Occurrences90"

End If

Call SumOfOccu
End Sub
Public Function SumOfOccu()


If Me![txtsupervisorstate] = "AZ" Then
Me.txtSumOfOccu = DSum("valueofoccurance", "occurrences365")
ElseIf Me![txtsupervisorstate] = "TX" Then
Me.txtSumOfOccu = DSum("valueofoccurance", "occurrences90")
End If


End Function
```

Now I can go back and start eliminating unnecessary subs/functions, clean up the naming conventions and make it overall 'cleaner'.

For anyone interested.. the queries look like this after I wrote them as a saved query.

```
SELECT OccuTable.ValueOfOccurance, OccuTable.ShortCodeOccurance, 
OccuTable.OccuranceDate, OccuTable.RollOffDate, OccuTable.Notes, 
OccuTable.AssociatedIDNumber
FROM OccuTable
GROUP BY OccuTable.ValueOfOccurance, OccuTable.ShortCodeOccurance, 
OccuTable.OccuranceDate, OccuTable.RollOffDate, OccuTable.Notes, 
OccuTable.AssociatedIDNumber
HAVING (((OccuTable.OccuranceDate) Between Date() And Date()-365) AND 
((OccuTable.AssociatedIDNumber)=[Forms]![OccuranceTracker]![txtAssociateID]))
ORDER BY OccuTable.OccuranceDate DESC;
```

again.. the only difference between the 2 is this one piece.

```
And Date()-365)
And Date()-90)
```

But everything works!

Thank you so much for the suggestions and pushing me to keep looking!